# Apache RedirectMatch where destination URL contains Querystring?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I haven't found a solution to this, since all of my searching and research points to query string related issues when you're going from a file with a query string, over to another URL. In my case, I'm just looking to go from a regular folder/file, etc., to a URL with a query string.

I have a working .conf file which contains various rules for my site. I'd like to add in another one that looks like this:

`RedirectMatch ^/webinar$ https://company.webex.com/company/onstage/g.php?t=a&d=123456`

`RedirectMatch ^/webinar/$ https://company.webex.com/company/onstage/g.php?t=a&d=123456`

I've modified the URL to be more generic. This redirects properly when I type in www.company.com/webinar however, it's not going to the above URL. When I type in the above URL directly in a browser, it loads up fine.

The redirect is taking me to a generic Webex page. This could be an issue with the redirect, but I think it has to do with how RedirectMatch is handling the query string on this URL. I'm at a loss.

*EDIT*

There might be an issue in how I now have 3 redirects happening. The first is the /webinar, second is the above URL, and the third is that the above URL redirects to another page where quite frankly, webex may be handling iframes. Not 100% sure. So could the second redirect be borking the third, etc? I can provide more specifics as far as the webex URL's if required.

**SOLUTION**

The issue here is that Webex can't handle a double redirect which is what's happening. Instead, I had to leverage a PHP page with a header redirect in a separate folder off of the TLD. The above RedirectMatch syntax is correct, but for some reason, Webex borks it.

Comment: I believe that there is an issue with the way the URL is being parsed in the first redirect. I've resorted to a PHP redirect with the physical directory. Not ideal, but felt it was the easiest given the potentially complex issue here.

Comment: We'd need to see the other rules in order to give an answer.

Comment: Those would be the only two rules in there. I think it's an issue with Webex, and not the actual syntax of the RedirectMatch. After some more research, the RedirectMatch can pass through to any URL, like this with a query string. So I'd consider this a moot point since I believe it's due to the Webex redirects.